# Node_save fails silently

Tags: nodes

I am trying to programmatically update a node with a value from another entity. When I call `node_save`, the function just "stops". There is nothing in watchdog or in my php_logs that would indicate that any issue was encountered.

```
$node = node_load($base_node->nid, FALSE, TRUE);

$node->field_product[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = array('product_id' => $entity->product_id->value());

dpm('This text prints.');

node_save($node);

dpm('This text does not print.'); //This line is never executed.
```

I have tried a variety of methods for saving the node including using entitymetadatawrappers on `$node`. So far, nothing I have tried has gotten me anywhere.

Thanks!

**Edit**:

A few more details on what I have tried/am trying to do.

This field is a product reference field that I am adding a reference to.

There is nothing at all in the php logs or the watchdog logs.

I am trying to do this as a part of custom rules action. I was originally using the `add item to list` action, but only one item was being added to the list (usually there will be 4-5). As a test, I tried to update and save the node manually (thus the code above).

I should have specified that part, but got a bit wrapped up in my own solution. Either way, it seems pretty odd to me.

**Edit** Part 2:

I have confirmed that the structure for `field_product` is correct. I am also doing checks to make sure that I am not referencing a non-existent field, etc.

I wasn't originally using `dpm`s for debugging, it just seemed like the simplest way to communicate my issue. Originally I was doing some further processing on my data that was not being done. Since that further logic isn't pertinent to the problem, I added a `dpm` as an example. There were no errors in the following logic and it wasn't dependent on the node save.

Comment: Do you get a WSOD? Did you check you server logs for PHP errors?

Comment: I don't get a WSOD. Everything continues as though nothing went wrong. There is nothing in the logs.

Comment: Please try to use `dsm($node->field_product);` to display the content and structure of that variable. Check if the structure of the value you're assigning is the same. Where are you executing this code also? Thanks!

Comment: I have done that, and the format is the same. This code is part of a custom rules action.

Comment: by doing $node->field_product[LANGUAGE_NONE][] you are implying that  $node->field_product[LANGUAGE_NONE][1] will be created if [0] already exists. Moreover are you sure it is 'product_id' and not 'value'. Last dpm may not be the best way to debug a rules action. use watchdog('debug', '<pre>'.print_r($var,true).'</pre>'); instead and make  sure the action is triggered by enabling rules debug in advanced options.

Comment: Updated post to provide further details. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you confirmed that $entity->product_id->value() is returning something valid and that node_load($base_node->nid, FALSE, TRUE) is returning a valid node? It seems extremely unlikely that it is actually failing to complete all the code without throwing any errors in the PHP/Apache or watchdog logs (unless your PHP error handling is incorrectly configured).

Comment: To debug further you could start putting dpm() calls in the node_save() function to try to pin down exactly where it is having issues. You can put a series of sequential numbers like dpm(1), dpm(2), etc. in all the conditional blocks in there and get a quick overview of how it is running through that function.

Comment: I have confirmed that both are returning expected values. I agree with you that what I am describing is extremely unlikely. And that is why I created this question, as I am at my wit's end regarding what the issue could be. I did consider going down the path of debugging node_save(), but figured that there was likely a more obvious solution that I was missing.

Comment: I did have a thought, would it maybe have something to do with Rules' recursion prevention? If rules thought that my function was recursive, it might kick out and not log it as an error? Just a thought.

Comment: Maybe, in which case your rules logs should say so right? Even still it would seem strange that your last dpm() doesn't run as I can't imagine rules would just exit processing entirely in the case of recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field structure you are using for your entity reference field is not correct. See [entityreference_field_schema()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entityreference!entityreference.install/function/entityreference_field_schema/7).

The correct column name is target_id, not product_id, so it should be like this:

```
$node = node_load($base_node->nid, FALSE, TRUE);

$node->field_product[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['target_id'] = $entity->product_id->value();

node_save($node);
```

This assumes you are using an entity wrapper to access the `$entity` object but not for accessing the `$node` object.

**[edit]**

Regarding your `dpm()` not firing, it is quite possible it is firing but you aren't seeing the output. This can happen depending on where you are calling it from.

A good alternative in these cases could be [dd()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7) or [watchdog()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7) since their output will be visible regardless of where you call it from.

Comment: I got my wires crossed. This is a product reference field, not an entity reference field. For a product reference field  product_id is the correct column name. I have tried alternatives to`dpm()` and it isn't making a difference. I've updated the post to try to provide some additional clarity